# Newly installed hard drive not visible

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid, sata

Motherboard was too old to install a  [sata 2 harddrive](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136344) So i bought a  raid controller  ("http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816132008")

In windows 7 , the device manager detects both devices and claims that the drivers are both updated. But it is not visible in My Computer.

There's an option for raid utility during boot up, but im not sure if i should mess with it. I just want this to be a raid0 drive to store stuff, but i have no clue what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the disks are still raw and have no file system on it. Go into `Control Panel/Administrative Tools/Computer Management` and select "disk management" from the left pane. In disk management, initialize and format the disks and they should show up in "My Computer".

Answer (score 0):

Many RAID cards come with special disk initializing and formatting software that you may need to run before the disk will be recognized.  That "RAID utility" you mention could be the only way to make things work.

If this isn't helpful, edit your question to include the exact model of your RAID card.  Don't make people go to Newegg to look it up--they're doing *you* a favor, not the other way.